# How to pass variable from source to destination machine using SSH?

Tags: unix, ssh

I have two machines A and B

I was trying to connect using SSH, after connecting to machine B , i want to execute a script at B but i also want to pass a variable from A server to the script of B as an argument to it. can you please suggest ?

Comment: Arrange to pass it as a parameter to the remote script (so that you can run something like `ssh hostB yourscript $yourvariable`)

Answer (score 0):

There are options in your client A `ssh_config` and in server B `sshd_config`, that control this. They are called `SendEnv` and `AcceptEnv` respectively. If you configure them and restart `sshd` server, then you should be able to use variables from server A to server B.